# How should I release a jQuery plugin to be ES5 and ES6 installable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ecmascript-6

I want to release a new jQuery plugin, but not sure whether to release it as ES6 (modern developers) or ES5 (anyone):

ES6 format is import and const:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
$.fn.plugin = function () { ... }
```

Whereas ES5 is IFFE and var

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.plugin = function () { ... }
}(jQuery))
```

The problem is:

- if I write it in ES6, I then have to transpile it to use in ES5
- if I write it in ES5, it's not usable in ES6 as `jQuery` is `null`

As one file and a small one to boot, using something like webpack would be major overkill and file bloat.

Is there a way to build something using ES6, then somehow have it transpiled and wrapped in the standard jQuery IFFE format and saved to a new file?

If I can do this with just NPM, that would be great; if not, then Gulp it is.

Comment: The major difference between your snippets is that one assumes a module system and the other doesn't - not ES5 vs ES6. Try Universal Module Definition.

Comment: Ah, you mean something like this? https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/jqueryPlugin.js

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You can even write your plugin in ES6 and let your transpiler add the UMD header.

Comment: Hey @Bergi, just wanted to say thanks; your pointer and that template have achieved exactly what I want. My little plugin now works happily whether imported or loaded directly into the browser. Cheers!